# Assign formula for each cell in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA. I would appreciate some help with advices about how to assign a formula for each cell in a table that changes its data daily.

Here is the table I need to update. What I need to do is calculating the goal for each day using the formula:  `=(K12-SUM(C2:C3))/(L13-1)`, where K12 equals to GOAL AG, minus the SUM of C2 till the current day, divided by the working days(L13) minus the day position (1 in this case since I need to start from 0). So basically I'd need to change the sum and the working days for each cell in column B to get daily goals. Is there a way to do this in VBA.

Note: The dates will be changing everyday so sometimes the table will have more days for calculating or less.

[image: TablePic]

This is what my code looks like. It calculates the goal for each day but I want to find a way to calculate the goal for each cell in a dynamical way, since everyday the dates will change:

```
'26
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[10]C[10]-SUM([@[REAL AG ]]))/(R[11]C[11])"
    '27
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[9]C[10]-SUM(R[-1]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[10]C[11]-1)"
    '28
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[8]C[10]-SUM(R[-2]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[9]C[11]-2)"
    '29
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[7]C[10]-SUM(R[-3]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[8]C[11]-3)"
    '3
    Range("B6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[6]C[10]-SUM(R[-4]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[7]C[11]-4)"
    '4
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[5]C[10]-SUM(R[-5]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[6]C[11]-5)"
    '5
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[4]C[10]-SUM(R[-6]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[5]C[11]-6)"
    '6
     Range("B9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[3]C[10]-SUM(R[-7]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[4]C[11]-7)"
    '10 oct
     Range("B10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[2]C[10]-SUM(R[-8]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[3]C[11]-8)"
    '11
     Range("B11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[1]C[10]-SUM(R[-9]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[2]C[11]-9)"
    '12
     Range("B12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[0]C[10]-SUM(R[-10]C[2]:RC[2]))/(R[1]C[11]-10)"
```

Comment: Why do you need the VBA do that... it's doable using simple excel-formula itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below piece of VBA code;

```
Sub code()

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:B" & lRow).Formula = "=($K$12-SUM($C$2:C2))/($L$13-(ROW()-2))"

End Sub
```

Output;

[image]

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time for helping me! The code worked fine. I'm just not sure about how does the next part work: (ROW()-2). Could you explain this for me?

Comment: Glad to help... so basically ROW() will fetch you the row number... as the formula is starting from B2 Cell, so ROW() in this cell will give you 2 (coz of 2nd row)... & in our calculation for day 1 i.e. 1st Oct 2022 should reference from 0, so that's why minus 2... collectively (ROW()-2)... now if we drag down the formula then day number referencing supposed to increase by 1, & ROW() actually does goes up as required...